# Eclipse plugin to run a script at startup

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I started with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39104382/6734995) question.

I know SO is not the place for this, but I cannot find tutorials for dummies on this subject.

Which option should I choose to create a plugin that will just launch a script when eclipse starts?

[image]

And after that how can I creare the code to override the earlystartup() so a new thread can be runned?

I just need a hello world into that.

Answer (score 1):

Un-check the option to use a template, you don't need a template just a bare-bones plugin. Then implement the [org.eclipse.ui.startup](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_startup.html?cp=2_1_1_192) extension point, and in the implementing class launch your "script."

Comment: If I don't ask too much, could you please provide a simple implementation of `org.eclipse.ui.startup`? Also, when I try to import it, and press `ctrl+space` it changes to `IStartup`

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service. Read the documentation provided and make an attempt. Come back with specific questions about your attempt.